# Powershell 2 freezing on Select-String ".*_.*=-1"

Tags: performance, powershell, regex

this might seem like stupid Q but I have PS problem:
like the title says I try something like:

```
 $all = gci D:\work\
 $all | Select-String ".*_.*=-1"
```

(im looking for config option that has value -1 and _ in name)
Problem is that PS freezes, aka it doesnt finish in reasonable time, ctrl +c doesnt work. 
Ofc you could say that data is just to much for it to process, but problem is that grep takes like 1-2 secs on same folder and same regex.

Grep command is (originally it didnt have -r but I added it after some comments, grep is still fast but it takes 20-30 sec)

```
grep ".*_.*=-1" -r D:\work\*
```

EDIT:

```
$all  | ForEach-Object {echo $_.Name;  $_|Select-String ".*_.*=-1"      }
```

shows slowly filenames... I guess the problem is that Regex speed in PS is pathetic...

Comment: Could you please show the full grep command as well.

Comment: i could and i did :)

Answer (score 1):

Specific:
Try tweaking a regex to

```
 [^_]*_[^=]*=-1
```

equivalent grep version :

```
grep -P '[^_]*_[^=]*=-1'
```

General:
The regex implementations are different, so that is the reason for different behavior. I don't know specifics of powershell regex implementation, so I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: is the regex semantics the same for my example (in grep and PS)

Comment: I don't know. Even grep as more than 1 regular expression syntax. Regular, extended and perl version. I'm not experienced with the PS version.

Comment: btw it still freezes

Comment: Could you give more details on the data sample, like size in MB?

Comment: btw maybe PS tries to go through directories while grep skips them "X is a directory"

Comment: idk how to get total size, but all has ~500 entries

Comment: Grep does not go recursively, unless `-r` flag is given.